# how to get all rows in column to insert db in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to insert all rows which showing view in a table but it insert only one row with value '1' not all rows and not that id's contain in a column:

view:

```
echo"<table class='table table-hover type-list2'id='traineeList'>
                    <tr class='success'>
                        <th>Trainee ID</th>
                        <th>Trainee Name</th>
                        <th>Present</th>
                    </tr>";
            foreach($list['trainee'] as $row){ 
                echo "
                    <tr><td>".str_pad($row->TraineeID,7,"0", STR_PAD_LEFT)."</td>
                        <td>".$row->Name."</td>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' name='.$row->TraineeID[]' value='".$row->TraineeID."' checked></td>
                    </tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
```

controller:

```
public function insertAttendance(){
    $data = array('TraineeID'>=$this->input->post('TraineeID'));
    $attnDate=$this->input->post('attnDate');
    $classHour= $this->input->post('classHour');
    foreach ($data as $id){
        $query="INSERT INTO `tbl_attn_temp` (TraineeID, Date, classHour) VALUES ('".$id."','".$attnDate."','".$classHour."')";
        $this->db->query($query);
        redirect('attendance/index/');

    }
```

Comment: please anybody help me...

Comment: Your loop will be execute only one time because  `$data = array('TraineeID'>=$this->input->post('TraineeID'));` wrong code

Answer (score 0):

see the given link for your question
http://codefury.net/2009/12/insert-multiple-rows-into-a-database-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect function should be placed outside of your `foreach` loop, probably. Looking at your code, your `foreach` loop will run only once and then redirect you to another page.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

```
    foreach($_POST['TraineeID'] as $key => $id) {

        $attnDate=$_POST['attnDate'][$key];
        $classHour= $_POST['classHour'][$key];

        $query="INSERT INTO `tbl_attn_temp` (TraineeID, Date, classHour) VALUES ('".$id."','".$attnDate."','".$classHour."')";
        $this->db->query($query);
    }
     redirect('attendance/index/');
```

Comment: 'TraineeID' not post by any way, is there any another way to receive 'TraineeID'?

Comment: You need to post traineeID.

Comment: how do I? $_POST is super global, netBeans hint do not use this. $TraineeID=$this->input->post('TraineeID'), it's also not post 'TraineeID'. really don't get.